# Convertir / en - en SQL

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Tengo una consulta `SQL` que devuelve entre otras cosas, un campo de fecha, y en la consulta necesito obtener las filas que sean superiores a cierta fecha, ejemplo:

```
SELECT campo1, campo2, fecha WHERE fecha > 2018-01-01";
```

El problema es que el campo fecha me devuelve en este formato `01/01/2018`

Cual es la mejor manera de hacer ese **WHERE** para que funcione correctamente?

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar la estructura de la tabla? Si necesitas aplicar filtros sobre fecha lo óptimo seria que la columna fecha sea del tipo `DATE`, pero si no lo es, se pueden usar otras funciones para convertir una cadena a fecha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server, y la mayor parte de gestores de bases de datos se manejan con fechas en formato ISO 8601, es decir "aaaa-MM-dd" o bien "aaaaMMdd". Otra cosa es el formato que utiliza para mostrar los datos que pueden ser distintos en cada caso, pues depende de la aplicación que utilices, del tipo de cultura configurada en tu PC, etc.

En tu caso debes seguir el patrón que muestras, aunque con un pequeño detalle, debes rodear la fecha con comillas simples.

```
SELECT campo1, campo2, fecha WHERE fecha > '2018-01-01';
```